# How do i update Java 11 to Java 13?

Tags: java

I downloaded Java and it seems that I've downloaded Java 11.
How can I upgrade it to Java 13?

Thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: You could just uninstall Java 11 and install Java 13.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has released Java SE 14 already.

To install it add this ppa to the system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java14-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall java 11 and install the other one. If you do not uninstall java 11 then you need to change the java default configuration after you install the other version ( with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`)  and change your JAVA_HOME to the new jvm.

---

For the installation of open jre you can see this: https://openjdk.java.net/install/

Here is the open source JRE 14 version. This one you need if you want to run java application:
https://jdk.java.net/14/

### Next two you need if you are programming in java and you want some additional tools:

---

This is another place where you can find JDK version.
https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/14. This one you can install the same way that you install the JRE. So the link for installation is here: https://openjdk.java.net/install/

---

On this place you can find adopt JDK: https://adoptopenjdk.net/
This is open source JDK which are supported for longer time the bug fixes. Currently they have java 14. On the web site there is this place for installation:
https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot#linux-pkg
You just need to put the right version in the commands

I think inside https://adoptopenjdk.net/ you can also find JDK 13 if you are keen to use it.

---

Good luck to all!